# jquerymobile close dialog after opening another one

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

On page ABC, I pop up a jQueryMobile `first` dialog.

This dialog has a button that invokes a second dialog:

```
<a href="/second" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Second dialog</a>
```

I'd like to click on this button, with the following outcomes:

- `first` dialog is closed
- `second` dialog pops up
- When I close `second` dialog, I am left with page ABC

However, what happens is this:

- `second` dialog pops up
- When I close `second` dialog, I am left with `first` dialog
- Now I must close `first` dialog to be left with page ABC

jQueryMobile docs say that **When any link is clicked within in a dialog, the framework will automatically close the dialog and transition to the requested page, just as if the dialog were a normal page.**

How do I invoke the `second` dialog from the `first` dialog, while closing the `first` dialog?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
            $( "#link2" ).on( "click", function( event, ui ) {
                $("dialog1").dialog('close');
            }
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="example">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>test</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#dialog1" data-rel="dialog" id="link1">Open dialog1</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="dialog1">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>dialog1</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#dialog2" data-rel="dialog" id="link2">Open dialog2</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="dialog2">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>dialog2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try out code. And let me know if this worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Set a short time interval when you open the second popup.

```
$('#Popup1').dialog('close');

setTimeout(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage('#Popup2', {
        'role': 'dialog'
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that "opening" and "closing" dialogs are misnomers. You don't really "open" or "close" them, but rather "naviate to" or "navigate away" which works using the browser history - you're either adding the dialog as a page into the history, or removing it (going "back"). When navigating away from the first dialog to the other, it pushes the second dialog onto the browser history, but animating the first one with a close animation.

Once you get your head around that, finding a solution becomes pretty easy, and there are a couple options you can use.

1. Disabling changeHash on the dialogs opening will prevent them from being added to the history, so you can just open the second one, and when closing it, explicitly navigate back to the home page.
2. Change your link to first "close" the first dialog (which jQuery mobile handles by going "back" in history), then "opening" the second (which is navigating to the new page). this is the effect that you *think* you're getting now, because jQM animates it like that, but it's doing something different under the hood.